# converting string attributes into date and time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two model attributes called "date" and "time" that are strings:

```
004 > Event.first.date
  => "21/12/2019"
005 > Event.first.time
  => "7:30 PM"
```

I want to display the date and time of the event in the show page as:

```
Saturday, December 21 7:30 PM
```

My ruby version is 2.6.3.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method provided in Ruby.

You already have the time you would like to display, to get the date in your format you need to provide the following directives to `strftime`:

1. `%A` - Gives the full weekday name, for example `"Sunday"`.
2. `%B` - Gives the full month name, for example `"December"`.
3. `%d` - Gives the day of the month, zero-padded for example `09`

Combining these together you should be able to do the following:

```
  > "#{Date.parse(Event.first.date).strftime('%A, %B %d')} #{Event.first.time}"
  => "Saturday, December 21 7:30 PM"
```

Once again all the information on `strftime` is available in the [documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

Comment: I see you had the sense (unlike moi) to avoid converting `Event.first.time` to a `Time` or `DateTime` object and then back to the same string.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'time'

date_str = "21/12/2019"
time_str = "7:30 PM"
```

**Step 1: Use [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to convert strings to a `DateTime` object**

```
dt = DateTime.strptime(date_str + time_str, '%d/%m/%Y%H:%M %p')
  #=> #<DateTime: 2019-12-21T19:30:00+00:00 ((2458839j,70200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

**Step 2: Use [DateTime::strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) to convert the `DateTime` object to the desired string**

```
dt.strftime("%A, %B %d %l:%m %p") 
  #=> "Saturday, December 21  7:30 PM"
```

Note:

```
DateTime.parse("I never use DateTime::parse, Data::parse or Time::parse " +   
               "because you never know what you may get")
  #=> #<DateTime: 2019-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Use `strptime`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.strptime`:

```
date = Event.first.date
time = Event.first.time
dt = DateTime.strptime("#{date} #{time}", "%d/%m/%Y %l:%M %p")
```

So in your view:

```
dt.strftime("%A, %B, %d %l:%M %p")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your date and time in a single variable like this

```
Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 -0400 (EDT)
```

You can use the very handy `Date.parse()` function:

```
str = "Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 -0400 (EDT)"
date = Date.parse str
=> #<Date: 4910837/2,0,2299161>
puts date
2010-08-10
```

This is probably the simplest method to convert a string to a date.

Comment: `Date.parse` is useful but it's also able to stab anyone trying to parse U.S. dates or a mix of U.S. and non-U.S. dates. `strptime` is much safer. Try `Date.parse('10/31/2019')`.